# Gradle Project Sync Failed with SDK 4.0.3

Tags: android, gradle, syn

Facing following Error on my App."
Grade Project sync Failed(Editing, Debugging will not work properly)

i am using SDK 4.0.3 while Android version is 6.0.

Please support

Comment: Please post the actual entire error statement or the stack trace

Comment: @AmeyaKulkarni following message appears in the buttom of Android SDK when i try to sync my project"Failed to sync Gradle project 'app'
Error:failed to find target android-21 : C:\Users\ayazk\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1
<a href="install.android.platform">Install missing platform(s) and sync project</a>

Comment: When i checked the corresponding log file, quite long  logs were present, i will share on next message window

Comment: cant share logs here due to size issue. now idea how to attach some file here:(

Comment: From the error message it seems that SDK for that platform is not yet installed.. Pls try n install sdk21 from SDK manager ..it might solve the problem..